# Sorting a slice of integers

Tags: go

My intention is to sort the values given in the slice of ints . I do not want to use the sort package and want to implement the sort function . The issue is when I try to use a index to compare the slice elements i get out of bounds error . What is correct way to modify a slice ?

```
func sortSlice( sli []int ) {
   j := 0
   i := 1
   for range sli {

        if( sli[j] > sli[j+1] ) {
            var  temp int  = sli[j];
            sli[i] = sli[j]
            sli[j] = temp
        }
        j++
    }
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile, and for example has a reference to a variable `i`.

Comment: i updated the code . But anyway I used @gonutz comments as the answer ...Thks

Comment: Before , I was not aware that there is an inbuilt package for sorting , and used my own function. but **using sort package is very very fast**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `range` over `sli` meaning you iterate `len(sli)` times so `j` goes from `0` to `len(sli)-1`. Now you compare element `j` with element `j+1`. For the last iteration this means you compare element `len(sli)-1` with element `len(sli)`. This last index is the problem. There is no element `len(sli)` because `sli`'s indices go from `0` to `len(sli)-1`.

Also note that in Go you can say `sli[i], sli[j] = sli[j], sli[i]` to swap two items. That said, your code cannot work since there is no `i` defined anywhere.

Next on the list of issues is that this is not all of the bubble algorithm that I think you are going for. You only iterate over the slice once but this will not sort it. You would have to repeat the loop you have until no more swaps happen.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, you want to do your custom implementation, but not sure why don't want to use `sort` package. You can do custom sorting by overriding `go#interface`.

For example

You can write a custom sort in go and call it with the sort package. basically you can override sort function for interface and can change the behaviour according to your needs. you can create a struct that takes in your data, as per below example and override the functions Len() , Swap() , Less()

```
type Sortslice struct {
    Sli []int
}

func (s Sortslice) Len() int {
    return len(s.Sli)
}

func (s Sortslice) Swap(i, j int) {
    s.Sli[i], s.Sli[j] = s.Sli[j], s.Sli[i]
}

func (s Sortslice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if s.Sli[i] > s.Sli[j] {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

After making the structure you can pass your data into it and call the sort method over the []interface using sort.sort() function. this will use your logic to sort the slice.

```
var data = []int{5,6,8,1,9,10}
sortedSlice := Sortslice{data}   
sort.Sort(sortedSlice);
```

It's better to use `sort.Sort` since it takes care like what to do (use merge sort, quick sort).

But if you want to do everything by yourself follow the source code of [sort.sort()](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort) and in a similar manner write your custom things

source : https://yourbasic.org/golang/how-to-sort-in-go/

Comment: If you want to use the standard library, `sort.Ints(sli)` is simpler. And `sort.Slice` would be the next choice if you need a custom comparator.

Comment: yes, you're correct. I thought of it as the user didn't want to use the standard functions of the package and rather wanted to write his own and even if user wants to write their own custom sorting, they would need heap sort or merge sort depending on the length of slice (for better performance). I think best way is to override Sort.Interface and use sort method as per my comment.